# Call to a member function find() on null in PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I intend to use **PHP Simple HTML DOM**
To extract the links in [this link](https://www.technolife.ir/product-3303)

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
$url = "https://www.technolife.ir/product-3303";        
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$html_base = new simple_html_dom();

foreach($html_base->find('a') as $element) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $element->href );
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

But unfortunately I get this error while running:

```
Call to a member function find() on null
```

Comment: That can't happen in this code. `new` can never return `null`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `simple_html_dom($str)`?

Comment: @Barmar I tried your suggestion but it gave me this error:  `is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given`

Comment: @hanshenrik You can also try this code for this link yourself, to see the error that occurs

Comment: That's just a warning, your code *should* still work as expected. You're receiving it because the simple_html_dom library can take a path to a loadable file, but doesn't check if the parameter is a valid path before checking said file exists (simple_html_dom.php:1471). There's not an awful lot you can do other than suppress the warning or modify the library yourself.

Comment: @George Please explain a bit more, I just want to extract the links on this page, do I really need to use Curl? Or do you suggest another way to avoid this error?

Comment: https://techglimpse.com/php-script-extract-urls-webpage/

Comment: @hanshenrik `simple_html_dom` is not a user-written class, it's a third-party library https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Which of these lines throws that error? What have you tried to resolve it? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.technolife.ir/product-3303 serves gzip-compressed content even when the client doesn't request compression, hence you just get a bunch of binary gzip-compressed data which looks like complete junk to simplehtmldom and causes it to crash.

luckily libcurl has built-in support for decompressing gzip, which can be enabled with `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');`

that said, you should use DOMDocument over simple_html_dom,

```php
$html_base = new DOMDocument();
@$html_base->loadHTML($str);
foreach($html_base->getElementsByTagName('a') as $element) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $element->getAttribute("href") );
    echo "</pre>";
}
```